# SPX and Typescript - how to add references to SP.JS?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

I am trying to start learning the typescript and sharepoint framework. What I have been having trouble with is how to add references to SharePoint js files such as sp.js? For example, what I am trying to do right now is to open a modal dialog using the SP modal dialog framework available under SP.UI.ModalDialog.

Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The SPFx Examples are a place to learn SPFx

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples

Alas they hardly have documentation, and some archaic code patterns cry for a code review.
So don't just copy/paste code, always question if the code is correct!

The [TaxonomyPicker](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/4a4fccf69b075f4395230690d35bf45e0c4f5500/samples/react-taxonomypicker/src/controls/PropertyPaneTaxonomyPicker/components/TaxonomyPickerLoader.tsx) shows how to load (SharePoint) JavaScript libraries.

It *could* do with a recursive or Promise.all approach, but this sequential solution is better readable for medior level developers.

You import the loader

```
import { SPComponentLoader } from '@microsoft/sp-loader';
```

Then use

```
  private _loadSPJSOMScripts() {
    const siteColUrl = Utils.getSiteCollectionUrl();
    try {
      SPComponentLoader.loadScript(siteColUrl + '/_layouts/15/init.js', {
        globalExportsName: '$_global_init'
      })
        .then((): Promise<{}> => {
          return SPComponentLoader.loadScript(siteColUrl + '/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js', {
            globalExportsName: 'Sys'
          });
        })
        .then((): Promise<{}> => {
          return SPComponentLoader.loadScript(siteColUrl + '/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js', {
            globalExportsName: 'SP'
          });
        })
        .then((): Promise<{}> => {
          return SPComponentLoader.loadScript(siteColUrl + '/_layouts/15/SP.js', {
            globalExportsName: 'SP'
          });
        })
        .then((): Promise<{}> => {
          return SPComponentLoader.loadScript(siteColUrl + '/_layouts/15/SP.taxonomy.js', {
            globalExportsName: 'SP'
          });
        })
        .then((): void => {
          this.setState({ loadingScripts: false });
        })
        .catch((reason: any) => {
          this.setState({ loadingScripts: false, errors: [...this.state.errors, reason] });
        });
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ loadingScripts: false, errors: [...this.state.errors, error] });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a specific guidance article describing how to use SharePoint JSOM with SharePoint Framework client-side web parts available at https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-sharepoint-using-jsom. The article explains the different possible approaches of loading JSOM and their pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

This is what's needed for a working (SharePoint)popup. Parts are from the guidance doc, part is trial and error.

```
public componentDidMount(): void {
    SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/init.js', {
      globalExportsName: '$_global_init'
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js', {
        globalExportsName: 'Sys'
      });
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/ScriptResx.ashx?name=sp.res&culture=en-us', {
        globalExportsName: 'Sys'
      });
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js', {
        globalExportsName: 'SP'
      });
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/SP.js', {
        globalExportsName: 'SP'
      });
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/sp.init.js', {
        globalExportsName: 'SP'
      });
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js', {
        globalExportsName: 'SP'
      });
    });
  }
```

Then to show the popup you can add a method and use it on a button.

```
private showDialog() {
    console.log('yep');
    let options : SP.UI.IDialogOptions = {
      url: "https://your-url/",
      title: "ModalDialog",
      allowMaximize: false,
      showClose: true,
      width: 800,
      height: 830
    };
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
  }
```

And to test it you need to deploy your webpart, because in the workbench there is no styling...